# Cosmos DB Change Feed - What's the delay/latency?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

What is the "normal" latency between when a document is created/updated and when the Cosmos DB Change Feed processor picks it up?

Some operations we do are two-phase:  Create, then a few milliseconds later, Update.

I'm aware that only the latest version of a document will appear in the change feed.  But if the change feed is super-duper speedy, I'll end up processing both versions of the document.  Double RU usage than necessary because I only care about the "final" version.

Sure, I'll design my processor so that it doesn't care.  And sure, I doubt there's any set-in-stone guarantees.  But I *am* still curious, and wonder if anyone's had any experience (and paid attention to this particular detail) before.  In a few weeks, I might be able to come post my own experiences, too.

**EDIT**:  Digging around, I found FeedPollDelay.  Looks like 5 seconds by default.  So I suppose the answer is "the delay/latency is whatever I want it to be".  Which is convenient in terms of RU usage, but mildly disappointing just because it's a polling architecture. Makes sense though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is actually two-fold. The Change Feed is a feature in Cosmos DB that will publish changes as they happen, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#features-of-change-feed) though:

> Only the most recent change for a given item is included in the change log. Intermediate changes may not be available.

So it could occur that if your insert and update operation happen in-between your checks for changes, you'll get the update version instead of 2 separate changes.

On the other hand, it seems you are using the Change Feed Processor, which is a library that helps you consume this endpoint (it's one of [several available options](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/read-change-feed)). As you mentioned, the CFP Library works as a polling mechanism under the hood:

1. It polls for changes and sends it to your `ProcessChangesAsync` implementation, so it feels as a push model from the developer point of view.
2. After your `ProcessChangesAsync` implementation finishes, it will poll right away for more changes, **with no delay**.
3. If there are more changes, it goes back to #1. If there are no more changes, it will hold for the configured `FeedPollTime` as you described, and poll again.

This difference is important because if your changes are continuous, then the only delay in the change-detection comes from the speed your `ProcessChangesAsync` implementation can deal with them.